# How to convert below array data to object with property (json) in javascript or es6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My array

```
const array = [2,3];
```

and I want object like

```
"media" :[{"mid":"2"},{"mid":"3"}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `map()` to create the array of objects. It should be a simple 1-liner.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far and where you are facing problem.

Comment: That's not an object. It's a property inside an object, the object should have `{}` around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the desired array and then you can create an object and assign the array to the `media` key.

```js
const array = [2, 3];
const obj = { media: array.map((item) => ({ mid: item })) };

console.log(obj);
```